# Installing Giraph on HDInsight using script actions

Tags: azure, hadoop, msdn, azure-hdinsight, giraph

I'm trying to install Giraph on HDInsight cluster with hadoop, using script actions.
After 30+- minutes when deploying the cluster, an error shows up.

> **Deployment failed**
>
> Deployment to resource group 'graphs' failed. Additional details from
>   the underlying API that might be helpful: At least one resource
>   deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for
>   details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for reporting this issue. We found what the issue is and fixed it.

**Issue:** There’s a deadlock when the Giraph script is provided during cluster creation. The Giraph script waits for /example/jars to be created in DFS (Wasb/ADLS), but /example/jars can only be created after the Giraph script completes. This issue doesn’t repro for runtime scripts since at the point the script is run, /example/jars has already existed.

**Note:** We have created and deployed the fix for the scripts. And I have also tested creating a cluster with the updated version, which works fine. Please test on your side and let me know.